# 403 error on my Python REST API with Wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, api, rest

I am following a simple example (or what I thought was simple) of creating a python script that used the REST api to connect to wordpress.

However, I am getting a 403 error.  My credentials are correct because I can log in with them.

I have been working over this for awhile now.  Can anyone see where my error might be?  Thank you.

```
url = "https://prod-wp.xxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
user = "xxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxxx"
credentials = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}
response = requests.get(url , headers=header)
print(response)
```

`<Response [403]>`

**EDIT**

I have changed the code and this seems to work.

```
import requests
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
BASE_URL = 'https://website.com/wp-json'
WP_URL = os.getenv("WP_URL")
WP_USERNAME = os.getenv("WP_USERNAME")
WP_PASSWORD = os.getenv("WP_PASSWORD")


def get_headers():
    wp_credentials = {'username': WP_USERNAME, 'password': WP_PASSWORD}
    jwt_response = requests.post(f'{BASE_URL}/jwt-auth/v1/token', json=wp_credentials)
    jwt_token = jwt_response.json()['token']
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % jwt_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }
    print(f'Headers are equal to: {headers}')
    return headers


get_headers()
```

Comment: It's simpler to use `requests.get(url, auth=(username,password))` instead of building the authorization header yourself.  I'm guessing that you're not doing the encoding correctly.

Comment: Thank you, John.  I will try that.

Comment: Weird, I am getting an `import "requests" could not be resolved from source`.  I tried installing again just to see.  Still getting a 403 with it.

Comment: Are you sure the api uses http basic auth?  Maybe it uses some other authentication scheme?

Comment: I think you are correct.  I have updated my code and this seems to work.  Thank you for helping me think about it differently.